# using packagemaker on mac os

Tags: java, macos, packagemaker

i want to make the installation package on the mac os of my java application using the package maker. is there any one having the link that will show step by step guidance for performing this.

Answer (score -1):

See [Java Deployment Options for Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/00-Intro/JavaDevelopment.html) on the [Apple Developer site](http://developer.apple.com/). Here's an [`ant` build.xml](http://robotchase.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/robotchase/trunk/build.xml?revision=66&view=markup) file with targets to compose a Mac application bundle and create a `.dmg` disk image. Alternatively, consider using Java Web Start, also supported by that project.